# Which WPF Control Suite?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

If you were to buy one control suite for WPF, which would it be?

EDIT - I know that this is vague and understand that the answer might be different depending on the exact requirements. I guess what I'm getting at is that there are numerous WPF control libraries out there (e.g. Infragistics, Telerik, Syncfusion to name but a few) and instead of forking out for a different one per project because that is the best fit right now, based on experience with costs, upgrades, support, etc. who would you choose as a "preferred" supplier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what I have learnt from this and from looking around at all of the different vendors is that they really do all offer something slightly different in different areas. To pick a suite before confirming your requirements is not sensible.

Having determined your high level requirements you can then go through each of the suites and find the short list of vendors who do what you need.

In the meantime, I think I'm going to still with Infragistics (if anyone's interested)

Answer (score 1):

Going on the assumption that you are looking for the best control suite, to suite most general purpose uses, I'd recommend [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/). They have a pretty wide range of controls, in basically every UI platform on the Microsoft stack. WPF, WebForms, WinForms, Silverlight, and ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I would buy me a Visual Studio license with all the standard controls.. harrr

Answer (score 0):

Surely it would depend on what controls you wanted? Or your budget? This is kind of a vague question since it depends heavily on the requirements.

Personally I've only used some of Actipro's stuff but it seems well written.

Comment: I know that the question was vague...I've edited to explain further

Answer (score 0):

Try the WPF Toolkit from Microsoft, its even free...

Answer (score 0):

I use **Telerik** WPF Controls about a year. Great controls  with good support.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely evaluate DevExpress.
Their WPF and SL controls have the same foundation = same functionalities, same APIs.
Their grid is available for Winforms, ASPx, MVC, WPF and SL.
Their control set is one of the best there is.

http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/95200/327082.aspx#327082

Comment: it run so slow,too heavy